# What does this awk scripts do?

Tags: awk, makefile

I found this in a embedded in a Makefile:

```
awk '/@/{print "  \"" $$_ "\\n\"" }' file
```

I know the prototype of awk is:

```
awk 'pattern {action}' file
```

But what does `@` and `$$_` mean?

Comment: did you find this embedded in a Makefile? A little more context would help. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter ,yes,it's in a makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the underscore character is simply a variable in this case.  And since it is not initialized, it has the value of zero.  Thus, `$_` is equivalent to `$0`, which refers to the entire line that was processed.  I think that it could also have been written `$x` since x would be an uninitialized variable.

Since it appears in a makefile, two dollar signs are needed (it is a special character in a makefile) to produce a single dollar sign in the command.

And as already mentioned by Nemo, the `@` is simply the pattern.  Any line containing `@` would be matched.

Answer (score 1):

OK that is weird.  It appears to have the same effect as:

```
awk '/@/{print "  \"" $_ "\\n\"" }' file
```

And also the same effect as:

```
awk '/@/{print "  \"" $0 "\\n\"" }' file
```

That is, it takes any line of the form `foo@bar` and converts it to `"foo@bar\n"` (with two leading spaces).  Lines without an `@` get dropped because they do not match the pattern.

But I have never seen the double-dollar sign, nor the use of `$_` as a synonym, nor can I find them documented anywhere...

Comment: there's nowhere that says `$_` and `$0` are exclusive synonyms because they simply aren't in `awk`. `POSIX` spec says variables must be `ASCII` alphanumeric `[0-9A-Za-z]` or underscore `_`, not beginning with a number, and not one of the system ones like `SUBSEP` `NF` etc, and nearly no limit on variable name length. (`gawk` accepted a 1024-char variable name just fine). So going by the spec, `_` is simply an unused variable that the user may utilize for ANY purpose…...

Comment: …… When it's used previously undefined, then `_` inherits the same properties as any new variable - either numeric zero (0) or empty string `""` - it selects it for you based on context. You can use `_` to loop through columns if you like ::: `for (_ = _<_; _++ < NF; ) $_ ^= 5` :: here I raised the value of every column to its 5th power.

Comment: another convenient use. Say you're trying to make comparisons and wanna ensure it's string-based, you can do a gapless string concat against fields if `_` is either undefined or empty string :::::::::::::::: ::::::::::: ::: e.g. `if (_$3 < "25c-89-37") { … }`. Gapless string concat is something not explicitly discussed by the spec, but it's perfectly conformant to the spec itself.