# How to escape backslash and double quotes with awk

Tags: bash, awk, escaping

I have some awk that rearrange a line. I would like to escape one of the variables (e.g. $_), in such way that `"` and `\` are escaped with a backslash.

Example:

```
echo "Ehm, \"hi\", he \\ said" | awk '{$1="" ; print "\"" $_ "\"" }'
" "hi", he \ said"
```

(do not change the echo, normally I read from a file that has `Ehm, "hi", he \ said` in it).

I would like to have

```
" \"hi\", he \\ said"
```

instead. How can I do this? Is there a function in awk that can do this?

Comment: What is `$_` in the context of an awk program?

Comment: @Tom that means, rest of the line

Comment: As mentioned in answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6293790/2088135), it looks like `$_` ends up working because `_` evaluates to `0`, so you end up with `$0`. It is not typical to see `$_` in awk scripts. Use `$0` to refer to the whole line.

Comment: I think you should decouple the part of `$1=""`, because it is generating noise. Unless it is strictly necessary, the question would benefit from it. Also, from your update it looks like you just want to add `\` to any `"` or `\` found in the string, isn't it the case at the end?

Comment: @fedorqui Your comment was not marked up well, as I can't understand what you have written

Comment: Wops, sorry! I wanted to say: from your update, it looks like you just want to add \ to any `"` or \ found in the string. In that case, `gawk '{print gensub(/("|\\)/, "\\\\\\1", "g")}' file` would make it.

Comment: Your question seems rather confusing, are you asking: "How can I replace characters in a string?"

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat tst.awk
function foo(str) {
    sub(/^[^[:space:]]+/,"",str)   # remove first field
    gsub(/["\\]/,"\\\\&",str)      # put \ before each \ and "
    return "\"" str "\""           # surround with quotes
}
{ print foo($0) }
```

Test:

```
$ echo "Ehm, \"hi\", he \\ said" | awk -f tst.awk
" \"hi\", he \\ said"

$ cat file
Ehm, "hi", he \ said

$ awk -f tst.awk file
" \"hi\", he \\ said"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a string with Bash, you have to take into consideration what `echo` itself is performing with the double quotes. Find it here:

```
$ echo "Ehm, \"hi\", he \\ said" | awk '1'
Ehm, "hi", he \ said
```

Using single quotes solves part of the problem:

```
$ echo 'Ehm, \"hi\", he \\ said' | awk '1'
Ehm, \"hi\", he \\ said
```

This being said, now it is time to add quotes around the string. For this, we use `print` with three arguments --> `print "\"", $0, "\""`.

To remove the first field, we can do it [in the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38145415/1983854):

```
$ echo 'Ehm, \"hi\", he \\ said' | awk '{sub(/^\S+\s*/, ""); print "\"", $0, "\""}'
"\"hi\", he \\ said"
```

If we just blank it, it looks like we get what your desired output was:

```
$ echo 'Ehm, \"hi\", he \\ said' | awk '{$1=""; print "\"", $0, "\""}'
" \"hi\", he \\ said"
```

Comment: Why use `sprintf` and then add `1` to print, when you can just use `printf` (or even just `print`)?

Comment: The echo was only an example, normally `Ehm, "hi", he \ said` is in the file that awk processes. The awk doesn't escape anything of the original variable at the moment

Comment: @TomFenech ha! Because I was too much into changing the string that I lost focus :D

Comment: @PeterSmit then you should edit your original question to make it more representative.

Comment: I specifically asked in the question for a function in awk to do the escaping, but I'll clarify it more

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you resort to awk? Bash is perfectly able to perform string manipulations:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r ignored line <<<'Ehm, "hi", he \ said'
line=${line//\\/\\\\}
line=${line//\"/\\\"}
echo $line
```

**Output**

```
\"hi\", he \\ said
```