# Using awk to filter a CSV file with quotes in it

Tags: awk

I have a text file with comma separated values.
A sample line can be something like

```
 "Joga","Bonito",7,"Machine1","Admin"
```

The " seen are part of the text and are needed when this csv gets converted back to a java object.
I want to filter out some lines from this file based on some field in the csv.
The following statement doesnt work.

```
 awk -F "," '($2== "Bonito") {print}' filename.csv
```

I am guessing that this has something to do with the " appearing in the text.
I saw an example like:

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*"
```

I am not sure how this works. It looks like a regex, but the use of the last * flummoxed me.

Is there a better option than the last awk statement I wrote?
How does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape backslash and double quotes with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119155/how-to-escape-backslash-and-double-quotes-with-awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a bit more through test file:

```
$ cat file
"Joga","Bonito",7,"Machine1","Admin"
"Joga",Bonito,7,"Machine1","Admin"
```

Using regex `^\"?` ie. *starts with or without a double quote*:

```
$ awk -F, '$2~/^\"?Bonito\"?$/' file
"Joga","Bonito",7,"Machine1","Admin"
"Joga",Bonito,7,"Machine1","Admin"
```

Comment: Why is the ~/ needed ?

Comment: `$2 == "foo"` matches the whole field, `$2 ~ /foo/` denotes regex match. `$2=="foo"` is the same as `$2 ~ /^foo$/`.

Answer (score 2):

Since some parameters have double quotes and other not, you can filter with a quoted parameter:

```
awk -F, '$2 == "\"Bonito\""' filename.csv
```

To filter on parameter that do not have double quote, just do:

```
awk -F, '$3 == 7' filename.csv
```

Another way is to use the double quote in the regex (the command `?` that make the double quote optional):

```
 awk -F '"?,"?' '$2 == "Bonito"' filename.csv
```

But this has a drawback of also matching the following line:

```
"Joga",Bonito",7,"Machine1","Admin"
```